# iPhone back up trouble

Tags: ios, backup

With a new iPhone 6S it never finishes with a back up, it says poor connection back up failed after 11 hours. My question is if you were to back up again, can't it begin from the 11 hours of data that it was backing up? Why does it almost finish? I have called Apple Tech twice and they don't really have an answer. My wi fi worked fine and backed up all the time with my iPhone 5s. My computer does not have a Wi-Fi connection so I cannot back up through iTunes.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  To what are you backing up your iPhone? The cloud or some other local device?  You might be able to get your computer to authorize to iTunes by tethering to your phone. Once it’s authorized then you can back up to it without any further internet connection.

Comment: Try backing up to the computer, not to iCloud, using a cable. That will be faster and more reliable.

In case you want Wi-Fi for your desktop, for about $10-20, you can buy a USB-wifi adapter the size of your thumbnail. Then you would have WiFi with your computer.